# How to extract variables when replacing multiple strings with sed

Tags: sed, regex-group

I have a file with multiple lines of

```
When i use the connection and request TEXT1 using mystring1.service
When i use the connection and request TEXT2 using mystring2.service
When i use the connection and request TEXT3 using mystring3.service
```

and I would like to replace it with

```
When i send a systemctl command through ssh and request TEXT1 using mystring1.service
When i send a systemctl command through ssh and request TEXT2 using mystring2.service
When i send a systemctl command through ssh and request TEXT3 using mystring3.service
```

where i pass in the 2 words after **request** and **using** into the new string.

I am trying to use sed and replace them with groups, it is however not working:

```
sed "s/When i use the connection and request ([\S]+) using ([\S]+)/When I send a systemctl command through ssh and request \1 using \2/g" input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: you dont need to substitute the entire line with `s///`, just the bits of the line which need replaced and then the bits that you want to replace them with.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the minimal thing first (as suggested by @NateT):

```
sed 's/use the connection/send a systemctl command through ssh/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your `sed` command. First, you need to use the -r option, or you need to escape the parenthesis and the `+` characters. Also, if you're going to use the `\S` token with `sed`, you don't need to square brackets. Here is a command equivalent to the one that you presented, but without the errors:

```
 sed -r 's/When i use the connection and request (\S+) using (\S+)/When i send a systemctl command through ssh and request \1 using \2/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Or escaping the characters without the `-r` option:

```
sed 's/When i use the connection and request \(\S\+\) using \(\S\+\)/When i send a systemctl command through ssh and request \1 using \2/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Of course, `\S` is nonstandard, so this will not work portably. The standard character class `[^[:space:]]` does the same thing POSIXly.